# Specific query optimization on MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table into MySQL DB (version 5.1.x), with the name **table**. Its columns are:
**id**, **double_col_index1**, **double_col_index2**, **flag**, **col_index_1**, **a_date_col**, **col_index_2**, **col_index_3** with the following indexes:

- a single index on **double_col_index1** and **double_col_index2**
- an index on **col_index_1**
- an index on **col_index_2**
- an index on **col_index_3**

Now, I have the following query:

```
UPDATE `table` t1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT t2.id FROM `table` t2 
    WHERE t2.double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
        AND t2.double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
        AND flag = 'true' 
        AND (col_index_1 = '' OR a_date_col < '1920-11-10 00:00:00') 
        AND 
        (SELECT count(t3.id) FROM `table` t3 
            WHERE t3.double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
            AND t3.double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
            AND t3.col_index_2 = t2.col_index_2 
            AND t3.col_index_3 = 'fake_col_index_3_1') > 0 
        AND 
        (SELECT count(t4.id) FROM `table` t4 
            WHERE t4.double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
            AND t4.double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
            AND t4.col_index_2 = t2.col_index_2 
            AND t4.col_index_3 = 'fake_col_index_3_2') > 0)  tbl 
ON t1.id = tbl.id SET col_index_1 = 'fake_value';
```

**Question**: I would need to improve this query, to give a better performance if possible. Would anyone have any suggestions on this?

---

One idea would be to use instead of `INNER JOIN` an `t1.id in (...`. What is your advice on this?

Comment: Where are the stats? The Explain plan? The table structure?

Comment: Pls include the results of the explain in the question. If your mysql version cannot run explain on update, then turn the update into a select and include the explain for that.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea of the join would be to do it as follows.

```
UPDATE `table` t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t2.id 
    FROM `table` t2 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT col_index_2
        FROM `table`  
        WHERE double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
        AND double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
        AND col_index_3 = 'fake_col_index_3_1'
    ) t3 
    ON t3.col_index_2 = t2.col_index_2 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT col_index_2
        FROM `table`  
        WHERE double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
        AND double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
        AND col_index_3 = 'fake_col_index_3_2'
    ) t4
    ON t4.col_index_2 = t2.col_index_2 
    WHERE t2.double_col_index1 = 'fake_value1' 
    AND t2.double_col_index2 = 'fake_value2' 
    AND flag = 'true' 
    AND (col_index_1 = '' OR a_date_col < '1920-11-10 00:00:00') 
)  tbl 
ON t1.id = tbl.id 
SET col_index_1 = 'fake_value';
```

This may be quite a bit quicker but will depend on many factors. MySQL will not use indexes for joining against the sub queries.

However there is a big issue with this (and your existing query) in MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

*Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*

There is a way round this, by doing a query on the sub query